# argparse: opening multiple files and ignoring error if one doesn't exist?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to obtain multiple file names and contextually opening them by using the `type=argparse.FileType("r")` argument:

```
PARSER.add_argument(
        "-f",
        "--files",
        nargs="*",
        type=argparse.FileType("r"),
        default=sys.stdin,
        help="""
        One or more file names. If this flag is missing,the script will read from STDIN
        """,
    )
```

If the script receives the name of a file which doesn't exist, it will rightfully print an error and exit, like so:

```
~/files>python script.py -f file1.txt file2.txt
usage: script.py [-h] [-f [FILES [FILES ...]]]
script.py: error: argument -f/--files: can't open 'file2.txt': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.txt'
```

Is there a way to handle this error such that the user is informed that one (or multiple) file doesn't exist, but continue executing the script on those files that do exist?

Obviously I could remove the type argument and manually open each file I receive as input, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: as for me opening manually can be the best solution.

Comment: Try writing your own type function that handles this perhaps by returning `None` if the file doesn’t exist? See the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#type - I guess you’ll have to filter the `None`s out of the resulting list.

Comment: Opening the files after parsing is cleaner.  The original developer included this `FileType` as a convenience for quick scripts that opened a few input/output files.  It's an idea that hasn't aged well.